# Error: package com.huawei.hms.maps.util does not exist when using HMS Map SDK 5.1

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

My Android app worked well with Huawei Map SDK 5.0.0 or lower version. When upgrading to Map SDK 5.0.1 or above version however, I get the error: package com.huawei.hms.maps.util does not exist when using:

import com.huawei.hms.maps.util.LogM;
import com.huawei.hms.maps.util.AssetBitmapDescriptor;

I tried several solutions, but none of them worked. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issues on your Android app when using Huawei Map SDK 5.0.1 or above, you need to do the followings:

1. use Android API android.util.Log to replace com.huawei.hms.maps.util.LogM
2. for com.huawei.hms.maps.util.AssetBitmapDescriptor, use the corresponding method in BitmapDescriptorFactory to replace it. Please refer to the links for details:
   [Link 1](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-ground-overlay-0000001061997609) and [link2](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/bitmapdescriptorfactory-0000001050152411-V).

Comment: Thank you Zinna. You help me to resolve my problems.